# Wireshark Filters: Getting the packet that was sent before the filtered one

Tags: wireshark, smb

I am trying to create a filter in Wireshark that will grab all SMB responses that return "Error: STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE". I would also like the be able to grab the packet before the filtered ones. Here's an example:

```
No. Time        Source      Destination Proto.  Length  Info
26482   24.832997   192.168.1.62    192.168.1.4 SMB 288 Trans2 Request, QUERY_PATH_INFO, Query File Basic Info, Path: \1_CLIENTS\CLIENTS\ACME INC
26483   24.833122   192.168.1.4 192.168.1.62    SMB 158 Trans2 Response, QUERY_PATH_INFO
26484   24.833232   192.168.1.62    192.168.1.4 SMB 306 Trans2 Request, FIND_FIRST2, Pattern: \1_CLIENTS\CLIENTS\ACME INC\<.AC_
26485   24.833909   192.168.1.4 192.168.1.62    SMB 126 Trans2 Response, FIND_FIRST2, Error: STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE
```

The following filter grabs the "STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE" packets:

```
((ip.src == 192.168.1.4) && (ip.dst == 192.168.1.62)) || ((ip.src == 192.168.1.62) && (ip.dst == 192.168.1.4)) && (smb.nt_status == 0xC000000F)
```

But I would also like to get the packet previous to that one as well so I know which file path wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TShark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), part of the Wireshark distribution, to get an overview.
Run the following command:
$ tshark -r FS01-Test.pcap -R smb.nt_status==0xc000000f -T fields -e frame.number -e smb.nt_status -e smb.response_to -E header=y -E separator=, > smb.csv
Output:
frame.number,smb.nt_status,smb.response_to
6242,0xc000000f,6238
6247,0xc000000f,6246
6331,0xc000000f,6269
6338,0xc000000f,6336
Another example:
$ tshark -r FS01-Test.pcap -R smb.nt_status==0xc000000f -T fields -e frame.number -e smb.nt_status -e smb.response_to -e smb.search_pattern -E header=y -E separator=, > smb02.csv
Output:
frame.number,smb.nt_status,smb.response_to,smb.search_pattern
6242,0xc000000f,6238,\\B\\Di\\folder.jpg
6247,0xc000000f,6246,\\B\\Di\\folder.gif
6331,0xc000000f,6269,\\B\\Ex\\folder.jpg
6338,0xc000000f,6336,\\B\\Ex\\folder.gif